# Typescript generic function changing argument type

Tags: typescript, generics, types, interface

I have a question regarding generic function (specifically why i'm able to modify an object from specific type)

example :

```
interface UserConfig {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}

let user: UserConfig = {
    name: "Eyal",
    age: 23,
 };

function addTimestamp<T>(arg: T): T {
  return { ...arg, timestamp: new Date().toString() };
}

console.log(user); // {name: 'Eyal',age: 23}

user = addTimestamp<UserConfig>(user);

console.log(user); // { name: 'Eyal', age: 23, timestamp: 2022-06-29T16:28:31.524Z }
```

Why i'm able to mutate `user` variable when it should have `UserConfig` interface properties only (`name` and `age`)

As this won't work

```
...
user.timestamp = "xxxx" // ERROR - Property 'timestamp' does not exist on type 'UserConfig'
```

Comment: Typescript is just a superset of Javascript. Once compiled all the types are gone. So if you relax the TS rules enough to go through the compilation process, you can add whatever you want to a object, even if it has a type in TS. This is because TS is compiled into normal JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you are not mutating "user", you are creating a new object that has all the fields of user, plus the timestamp field--the original user object doesn't change.

TypeScript doesn't complain here because the new object you return is still *compatible* with the original type T--you've not changed or removed any existing properties, you've just added new ones. It's [structurally compatible](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play#example/structural-typing) with the original type.

```
interface UserConfig {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}

let user: UserConfig = {
  name: "Eyal",
  age: 23,
};

function addTimestamp<T>(arg: T): T {
  return { ...arg, timestamp: new Date().toString() };
}

let newUser: UserConfig = addTimestamp(user);

console.log(user === newUser); // false
console.log('timestamp' in user); // false
console.log('timestamp' in newUser); // true

let typeTest: UserConfig = (() => {
  return {
    name: 'Pizza',
    age: 49,
    isVeryCool: true
  }
})(); // compiles just fine

// @ts-expect-error
console.log(typeTest.isVeryCool); // doesn't compile if I remove the directive
console.log('isVeryCool' in typeTest); // true
```

You can argue that this is a weird thing to allow, especially given that TypeScript will block other kinds of related additions (for example, try removing the IIFE from my typeTest example and using the literal directly), but it's technically correct with the rest of the type system rules.